# Using graphicx with invoice results in strange PDF output

Tags: graphics, invoice

I try to create an invoice with a logo in the background. But I get a strange result when I use graphicx and invoice in the same document. Here is my minimal example:

```
\documentclass{scrlttr2}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{invoice}

\begin{document}
% foobar
\end{document}
```

It builds fine with pdflatex, but the resulting PDF file has this on it's first page:

> [2007/09/09] [2010/03/01] [2010/12/02] [2010/09/13] [2007/11/11]
>   [2007/09/09] [2007/09/09] [2010/03/01] [2010/03/01] [2010/12/02]
>   [2007/09/09] [2007/09/09][2010/03/01] [2010/01/28] [2007/09/29]
>   [2007/10/02] [2007/11/11] [2009/07/12]

After this, a page break happens and the expected output begins. The footer is also on the first page (where the dates are) and the second page (the first with actual content) has no footer. Starting with the third page, everything seems fine.

Is this a bug in either invoice or graphicx?

**Update:** This only happens with pdflatex, the DVI output does not show the dates.

Comment: I cannot see this (with current TeXLive 2011)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This is a bug, and had nothing to do with `graphicx` *per se*. Inside the `invoice` package you find

```
\input{fp}
```

and inside `fp.tex` you find

```
\def\NeedsTeXFormat#1{}
\def\ProvidesPackage#1[#2]{}
\def\DeclareOption#1#2{}
\let\ProcessOptions\relax
```

Both of these are wrong: `input` should use the `fp` LaTeX package, and if `fp.tex` is going to provide definitions for LaTeX commands it should first check if they are already loaded. (The above miss out the optional trailing arguments, which is where the odd text then comes from.)

Comment: To be clear, this can be fixed in `invoice` by using `\RequirePackage{fp}` in place of `\input{fp}`. I guess it should be reported as a bug.

Comment: I wrote to the address specified on http://corff.de. Seems to be the same person.

Comment: Is there a way to fix this without changing the source? I'm using overleaf so I can't fix this and it's driving me mad.