# How to fix clash between pdfpages/graphicx and invoice package on overleaf

Tags: pdfpages, includegraphics, invoice

How to reproduce clash?

1. Use this template: https://nl.overleaf.com/latex/templates/invoice-template/rpdlzpjmkfmj
2. Add `\usepackage{graphicx}` or `\usepackage{pdfpages}`
3. Actually now that I test it, nothing happens.
4. Copy paste the exact same code to my main.tex in my own project, still fails!

This guy had the same problem
[Using graphicx with invoice results in strange PDF output](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/61113/using-graphicx-with-invoice-results-in-strange-pdf-output?r=SearchResults&s=1|53.1577)

Since I'm using overleaf I can't change the source material. It's sad because it's really a full featured invoice package otherwise.

Overleaf errorlog:
[https://pastebin.com/FyryKKbm]

Comment: the problem mentioned in the other question was fixed in the `invoice` package. Unfortunately overleaf is outdated for years with their tex version. Best thing to do: go to ctan, download the current version of `invoice` and upload it into your working folder. (and complain to overleaf that they should update their tex distribution)

Comment: Yes that would be a hard fix for this problem thank you

Comment: Ok that did fix my problems and turns out the changes suggested in previous answer were already fixed. For the record grab this [invoice package](https://ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/invoice) upload all files to folder called `invoice` except for invoicelabels.sty which I you need to put in root. Now change line `\usepackage{invoice}` to `\usepackage{invoice/invoice}` . Done

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was long ago fixed in the invoice package. Unfortunately overleaf is outdated for years with their tex version.

Best thing to do: go to ctan, download the current version of invoice and upload it into your working folder on overleaf (and complain to overleaf that they should update their tex distribution).